# How do you nest routes in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to express and node and I have this situation:

controller:

```
exports.find_by_IDN_post = (req, res) => {
    console.log('init')
    accidentDetail.findOne({ idn: req.body.idn }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
        console.log(data)
        res.status(200).send(data)
    })
}

exports.find_by_name_post = (req, res) => {
    accidentDetail.findOne({$or: [{'firstName': req.body.name}, {'middleName': req.body.name}, {'surname': req.body.name}]}, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
        res.status(200).send(data)
    })
}

exports.find_by_date_post = (req, res) => {
    accidentDetail.findOne({firstReg: req.body.firstReg}, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
        res.status(200).send(data)
    })
}

exports.find_by_accident_type_post = (req,res) => {
    accidentDetail.findOne({accidentType: req.body.accidentType}, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
        res.status(200).send(data)
    })
}
```

route:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const query_controller = require('../controllers/QueryController')


router.post('/idn', query_controller.find_by_IDN_post)
router.post('/name', query_controller.find_by_name_post)
router.post('/date', query_controller.find_by_date_post)
router.post('/accidentType', query_controller.find_by_accident_type_post)

module.exports = router
```

app

```
const queryRouter = require('./routes/query')
app.use('/query', queryRouter)
```

How do I nest the routes? I want to be able to access the routes like this:

```
localhost:3001/query/idn
localhost:3001/query/name
...
```

At the moment, I can't receive the **console.log('init')** when trying to access localhost:3001/query/idn.

Comment: How did you try to access the routes? Postman/Browser/cURL/etc.? It should work. What response do you get?

Comment: from a react client app, using axios.

Comment: Ok, and what is the response in axios? You can check it in *DevTools / Network* or try Postman.

Comment: I resolved the issue. I had a dynamic route /query/:id which was the problem making other routes unreachable. Thanks though!